# How to aggregate/concate strings with no duplicates in SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019, string-aggregation

I am very new to SQL Server and it stucks in one task related to the aggregation of data. I tried to put all information on the screen attached. Is there anyone that could support it? My current code is below, but it does not work (duplicates...). Many thanks in advance!

```sql
select distinct 
material, 
plant, 
STRING_AGG (exceptions, ';' ),
STRING_AGG (preferential_country, ';' )
from grs
GROUP BY material, plant
```

[image: Here is the image with all details]

Comment: Weird, they really forgot (or didn't manage?) to allow `DISTINCT` in `STRING_AGG`. See Gordon Linoff's answer here for a workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61554264/unique-values-with-string-agg-on-more-than-1-column

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I misunderstood part of your question. This is a bit messy, but I created a function to remove the duplicates.

```
CREATE FUNCTION remove_duplicate (@str varchar(100))
RETURNS varchar(100) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result varchar(100)
    SET @result = (SELECT STRING_AGG(ta.value,';') from(
                   SELECT DISTINCT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(@str ,';') 
                   )as ta)
    RETURN @result
END;
```

This is the query to create the output table where the exceptions are group together but there will be duplicates

```
SELECT distinct plant, 
       material,
       CASE WHEN count( distinct(preferential_country)) > 1 THEN 'QU' 
            ELSE MAX(preferential_country)
            END AS preferential_country,
            
       STRING_AGG(exceptions,';') as exceptions
       into new_table

FROM tableA
group by plant, material
order by plant
```

Lastly, you just need to use the function to remove the duplicates.

```
SELECT plant, material, dbo.remove_duplicate(exceptions) as exceptions from new_table
```

output:

```
plant   material    exceptions 
plant_1 Material_1  EU01;EU02;EU03;EU05
plant_1 Material_2  EU01
plant_2 Material_1  NULL
```

I couldn't get it to work in db fiddle but it's working on SSMS
[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5d2b5f194255bea3cc4a735f63498b3c)

Comment: Hi thanks for sharing. It works as expected for preferential_country, but exceptions are still not distinct (duplicates appear).